# GnuPG isn't working in PHP with nginx

Tags: php, encryption, nginx, gnupg

I think that probably I'm missing something, but I don't see it right now. I want create a simple form where users can encrypt automatically messages between them (form message to user2 -> encrypt(message) -> user2 receive it and decrypt). I'm using nginx, I installed gnupg following their instructions and add it to my php.ini (now it shows that GnuPG is enabled with GPGME Version 1.4.3 and Extension Version 1.3.6) I want use a specific keyring located at `/usr/share/nginx/.gnupg` I tried the following code:

```
$iterator = new gnupg_keylistiterator("developer");
foreach($iterator as $fingerprint => $userid) {
    echo $fingerprint." -> " . $userid . "\n";
}
var_dump($iterator);
```

And I just obtain the following response from var_dump:

> object(gnupg_keylistiterator)#1 (0) { }

Maybe my question is an idiot question, but I never used gnupg in php and I want learning, but I'm stunk since yesterday and I don't understand why it doesn't work...
Thanks for your time

Comment: nginx suggests you're running php-fpm (the php equivalent of fcgi). The php runtime is kept alive in between requests, so if you change the settings (the ini files), you have to restart the server (`sudo service php-fpm restart` and `sudo service nginx restart`) to load the new settings

Comment: Yes, I know I executed sudo service php5-fpm restart and sudo service nginx restart, I did an echo of phpinfo() and it shows that I have gnupg enabled but it isn't working yet for me... I don't know if I need specify the keyring of keys or another stuff... @EllasVanOotegem

Comment: What ini files did you edit? The files PHP-CLI uses, or all of the server files, too? check the ini files listed on a `phpinfo();` page, check the permissions (ownership etc...) for the gnupg file. Also check your logs. If iterating over the instance did not issue a `Invalid or unitialized gnupg object` error message, the problem lies elsewhere. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/marnold/php-gnupg-ubuntu/blob/master/gnupg_keylistiterator.c), that would be my first port of call

Comment: Where did you enforce the GnuPG home directory/keyring folder? Did you actually import the key to this keyring? GnuPG has per-(system)-user keyrings and does not share the contents among them. Make sure permissions on the GnuPG home directory are set up properly for the user running PHP (properly the web server user), GnuPG is _very_ picky about permission issues.

Comment: If I am not wrong I edited all server files, into phpinfo() it shows me one path of php.ini loaded /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini and that file has the extension added. I checked my nginx error logs and there is not any error there @EllasVanOotegem

Comment: I didn't enforce the GnuPG keyring folder... how can I do it? I set up the permissions of my current keyring located at /usr/share/nginx/.gnupg to www-data and the main folder ~/.gnupg too but it isn't working. I suppouse that it is the problem. Could you tell me a tip to fix it? Thanks @JensErat

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue is that you imported the keys to another keyring than later is searched for keys. GnuPG uses a per-(system)-user "GnuPG home directory", each containing individual keyrings. If you import a key as the administrator or a developer you import the key to your *own* keyring, while usually the web server running the PHP application is executed in another user context and will not find this key, resulting in an empty result when listing the keys from within PHP.

You can set this by setting up an environment variable before initializing the GnuPG binding.

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");  // Set GnuPG home directory to the temp folder
$res = gnupg_init();       // Initialize GnuPG
```

Obviously `/tmp` does not actually qualify as a reasonable directory, choose something where your application stores application data anyway. It should not be a directory accessible through HTTP.

As an alternative, `gnupg_import($res, $pubkey)` the key before using it (but this will result in some performance penalty for importing the key).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the following lines to my file: `putenv("GNUPGHOME=/root/.gnup/pubring.gpg"); $res = gnupg_init();` And I change the permission for my public key, I executed the file again but I'm getting the same result @JensErat

Comment: Never give other users access to the root directory, not even on test/development machines. Use some other folder, restrict permissions (only the web server user should be able to read and write), and finally make sure to import the key (`sudo -u www-data GNUPGHOME=/some/folder gpg --import key.pgp` or similar; or use PHP"s import as described above).